# Multidimensional array implementation to output Names and addresses in c#

Tags: c#

I have code like this, it requests input for name 1-5, and address 1-5, I want it to detect the name from the string, and in the search name section, it will request name from user input and outputs the address that was previously inputted.

```
string[,] input = new string[5, 2];
var Name = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

for (int a = 0; a < input.GetLength(0); ++a)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write($"Name {a + 1} : ");
        input[a, 0] = Console.ReadLine();

        if (Name.Add(input[a, 0]))
            break;

        Console.WriteLine("Name is already added! please input a different name");
    }

    Console.Write($"Address {a + 1} : ");
    input[a, 1] = Console.ReadLine();
}

while(true)
{
    Console.Write("\n==> Search Name : ");
    string nameSearch = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Name.Contains(nameSearch)) 
    { 
        Console.Write($"Address : {input[1, 1]}"); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        Console.Write("Name cannot be found!");
    }
}
```

I already succeeded to make output like this

> Name 1: example name a

> Address 1: ***cannot be coded yet***

> Name 2: example name b

> Address 2: ***cannot be coded yet***

> Name 3: example name c

> Address 3: ***cannot be coded yet***

> Name 4: example name d

> Address 4: ***cannot be coded yet***

> Name 5: example name e

> Address 5: ***cannot be coded yet***

And i want it to output:

> Name 1: example name a

> Address 1: address 1 *input from user*. ex: Mango number 7

> Name 2: example name b

> Address 2: address 2 *input from user*. ex: Pineapple number 12

> Name 3: example name c

> Address 3: address 3 *input from user*. ex: Blueberry number 44

> Name 4: example name d

> Address 4: address 4 *input from user*. ex: Apple number 3

> Name 5: example name e

> Address 5: address 1 *input from user*. ex: Cherry number 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple linear search will work.

```
while(true)
{
    Console.Write("\n==> Search Name : ");
    string nameSearch = Console.ReadLine();

    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.GetLength(0); i++)
    { 
        if (input[i, 0] == nameSearch) {
            Console.Write($"Address : {input[i, 1]}");
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    { 
        Console.Write("Name cannot be found!");
    }
}
```

You could check the hashmap before the loop, but you will still need to loop if it is found the hashmap contains the name.

```
while(true)
{
    Console.Write("\n==> Search Name : ");
    string nameSearch = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Name.Contains(nameSearch))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < input.GetLength(0); i++)
        { 
            if (input[i, 0] == nameSearch) {
                Console.Write($"Address : {input[i, 1]}");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        Console.Write("Name cannot be found!");
    }
}
```

Or, you could get rid of the hashmap and the 2d array and use a `Dictionary<string, string>` where the key is the name and the value is the address.

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int a = 0; a < 5; ++a)
{
    string name;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write($"Name {a + 1} : ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!data.ContainsKey(name)) {
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Name is already added! please input a different name");
    }
    Console.Write($"Address {a + 1} : ");
    var address = Console.ReadLine();
    data[name] = address;
}
while(true)
{
    Console.Write("\n==> Search Name : ");
    string nameSearch = Console.ReadLine();

    if (data.ContainsKey(nameSearch) )
    { 
        Console.Write($"Address : {data[nameSearch]}"); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        Console.Write("Name cannot be found!");
    }
}
```